# how to specify where to materialize dagster assets?

Tags: dagster

I'm new to dagster.

Currently when I materialize assets they end up in `/my-dagster-project/tmpav872908/storage/{assetkey}`

How do I specify where the assest should be stored?

Answer (score 2):

The default IO manager, fs_io_manager, stores and retrieves values from pickle files in the local filesystem. [See this section of the docs](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/io-management/io-managers).

You can override the default storage location of the fs_io_manager by adding
`"io_manager": fs_io_manager.configured({"base_dir": "/my/base/path"})` to your @repository `resource_defs`.
You will find more details on this in [the Dagster docs here](https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/io-managers#built-in-io-managers).

If you are looking to build out your data pipeline and save to a different location (like, say, Snowflake, S3, DuckDB, etc.) then keep on exploring I/O Managers - they are a very powerful feature of the Dagster platform.